# How can I create a boxplot using iqplot with a list of cubes in python-iris?

Tags: python-iris

I got a list of cubes and I would like to build Boxplot using python-iris.

I loaded all files and I try using matplotlib...

`hadgem2 = iris.load_cube(CLIMDIR + '/prec_EN-22_HadGEM2-ES_aml_ts_init:2040-end:2100.nc')`
`plt.plot(hadgem2)`
`plt.show()`

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GSa8.png)

Comment: Please include the error here and not as an external link

Comment: Boxplots are not implemented in Iris, so you will need to get hold of the numpy array `hadgem2.data` and pass that to matplotlib.

Comment: @RuthC Yes. I noticed that Iris has not yet been implemented. The only way was to turn it into a `numpy` array and use `matplotlib`... it worked. Thanks!